# Height and distance comparison.

Tags: geometry, ratio

A man 6ft tall casts a shadow 4ft long. At the same time, a  flag casts a shadow 50ft long. Find the height of the flag.

Comment: Differential geometry?

Comment: Any thoughts?  This looks like a routine trigonometry homework problem.  Your text will have examples....just look up similar triangles.

Comment: @lulu, this is *not* trig; it's simple arithmetic.  This should be certainly no later than 8th grade material and probably (much) earlier.

Comment: @Wildcard  agreed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use similar triangles to get the answer as:$$\frac{6}{4} = \frac{x}{50} \Rightarrow x=75$$ where $x$ refers to the height of the shadow cast by the flag.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Use proportions,

$\frac{6}{4}=\frac{x}{50}\implies x=75$

Answer (score 1):

[image: page 1]

Let AC and DF be man and flag respectively. BC and EF are their shadows respectively.

At the same time light rays from the sun will fall on the man and flag at the same angle.

Therefore,

$\angle$CAB = $\angle$FDE

$\angle$CBA = $\angle$FED

Also,

$\angle$ACB = $\angle$DFE = 90 degree

By AAA property triangle ABC and DEF are similar.

$\frac{AC}{DF} = \frac{BC}{EF}$

$\frac64 = \frac{x}{50}$

$4x = 50 * 6$

> $x = 75 ft$

Comment: I have tried to adapt your text, with the unique aim to help you in further texts (as you, English is not my mother language, and I have always appeciated to receive advices from others)

Comment: @JeanMarie I edited my answer to explain better. If still have something need to be improve. You can improve. I have no problem.